# Why is there no DirectX.log installation log?

Tags: directx

I am distributing a DirectX 9 app, using Aug 2007 version. DirectX is installed silently. A user is reporting the install is successful, but a problem occurs when running the app (cannot find d3dx9_35.dll). The **DirectX.log** does not exist on his system.

On my own PC, I can find DirectX.log (in \Windows\Logs), but the latest date in the file is two months ago, and does not reflect recent activity.

Is there a switch on DXSETUP.EXE to trigger the creation of a log file? Why would there be no log file?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind - I figured it out. The DXSETUP.EXE was not being invoked due to an error in the InstallShield script.

A DirectX log does indeed get created or updated.